# Everytime I use a sudo command it says ">>> /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu: syntax error near line 1 <<<"

Tags: command-line, sudo

I got the following error while using the `sudo apt-get update` command.

```
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sACwP.png)

I tried finding a solution, the end of the file is already

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

You can view the output for `pkexec visudo` [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnX0n.png)

You can view the file etc/sudoers:

```
s file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.

#

Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of

directly modifying this file.

#

See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.

# Defaults env_reset Defaults mail_badpass Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

Host alias specification

User alias specification

Cmnd alias specification

User privilege specification

root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Members of the admin group may gain root privileges

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

Allow members of group sudo to execute any command

%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

and  the file etc/sudoers.d/README

```
#
# As of Debian version 1.7.2p1-1, the default /etc/sudoers file created on
# installation of the package now includes the directive:
# 
#   #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
# 
# This will cause sudo to read and parse any files in the /etc/sudoers.d 
# directory that do not end in '~' or contain a '.' character.
# 
# Note that there must be at least one file in the sudoers.d directory (this
# one will do), and all files in this directory should be mode 0440.
# 
# Note also, that because sudoers contents can vary widely, no attempt is 
# made to add this directive to existing sudoers files on upgrade.  Feel free
# to add the above directive to the end of your /etc/sudoers file to enable 
# this functionality for existing installations if you wish!
#
# Finally, please note that using the visudo command is the recommended way
# to update sudoers content, since it protects against many failure modes.
# See the man page for visudo for more information.
#
```

and the output for `pkexec cat /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu` :

```
$(user) ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

**EDIT**: Now I get the following errors-

[image: screenshot]

I want a specific and precised answer. I am new to Ubuntu (14.04), please help me!

Comment: As the error message suggests, there is something wrong near line 1 of `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu`. Can you take a look at it and see if there is anything that looks wrong (say, a syntax error)?

Comment: How do I do that? @edwinksl

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the contents of the `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu` file.

Comment: How do i view the contents of the /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu file. @terdon

Comment: @PrabalRastogi Simply run the command `cat /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu` and [edit] your question to paste its output. You can view it in your favourite text editor as well though.

Comment: It says cat: /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu: Permission denied

Comment: @PrabalRastogi In that case use `pkexec cat /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu`, please.

Comment: @ByteCommander it says   $(user) ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL and takes no action.

Comment: @PrabalRastogi Please repeat this procedure for all files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` and for `/etc/sudoers` itself. Then [edit] your question to add the outputs, do not paste them in comments.

Comment: @PrabalRastogi Your `/etc/sudoers` file doesn't look like the default one given below. You are missing a lot of `#`s, for a start.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of your terminal](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695), instead copy/paste the text and use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @Jos thanks for pointing it out! I will just correct it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, **never edit `/etc/sudoers` manually**, always use `visudo`. Your problem was a syntax error in the file `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu` but it is now a malformed `/etc/sudoers`.

So, to fix it (now that you have removed any changes you may have made), run `pkexec visudo` and make the file look like this:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

    # Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>). Next, I suggest you just move the `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu` somewhere else so it doesn't cause issues:

```
pkexec mv /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu ~/
```

At this point, you should have a working `sudo`. If the `90-cloudimg-ubuntu` file was necessary, ask a new question with the contents of that file an we can help you put it back and fix the error.

Comment: You can also do `apt-get download sudo; dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile sudo*.deb | pkexec tar x ./etc/sudoers -C /` to get back the default `sudoers`.

Comment: @tredon with what name do I have to save the file?

Comment: @PrabalRastogi (the username is `terdon` not `tredon`, please use the autocomplete feature, I missed your precious comment). You don't need to specify a file name, did you run `pkexec visudo` or are you editing the file manually?

Comment: Sorry @terdon 
I ran     pkexec visudo and there is a syntax error on line 1, I copied your answer there, and then I pressed     CTRL+O, it asked me to save the file with etc/sudoers.tmp I pressed enter then Exit(CTRL+X) same as you mentioned.

Comment: @PrabalRastogi just accept the default. When you press Ctrl+O, it will ask you what to save the file as and will suggest some temp name like `/etc/sudoers.tmp`, don't change anything, just hit Enter and then Ctrl+X.

Comment: @terdon I just did that, it shows the following error
    prabal@rkstr:~$ sudo apt-get update
    >>> /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu: too many levels of includes near line 29 <<<
    sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu near line 29
    sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
    sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: @PrabalRastogi that's because you didn't do the last step in my answer: `pkexec mv /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu ~/`.